# Nearest color algorithm efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, beginner

Ok so my name is qqqiiiiiiiifdff and I made this code that simulates a perceptual color picker algorithm that selects the nearest color by iterating over the color array and selecting the minimum error, processing the calculations in a perceptual manner.

This is an example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

inline double square(double x){return x*x;}

inline double sRGBtolinear(double input){
    if(input < 0) return -sRGBtolinear(-input);
    else if(input > 0.0404482362771082) return pow((input+0.055)/1.055, 2.4);
    else return input/12.92;
}

inline double lineartosRGB(double input){
    if(input < 0) return -lineartosRGB(-input);
    else if(input > 0.00313066844250063) return pow(input, 0.4166666666666667)*1.055-0.055;
    else return input*12.92;
}

inline double lineartosRGBderivative(double input){
    if(input < 0) return lineartosRGBderivative(-input);
    else if(input > 0.00313066844250063) return pow(input, -0.5833333333333334)*0.4166666666666667*1.055;
    else return 12.92;
}

uint64_t selectnearest(uint32_t* palette, uint64_t palettelength, uint32_t color){
    uint64_t index = 0;
    double maxerror = 1.0/0.0;
    for(uint64_t i=0; i<palettelength; i++){
        double color1[3];
        double color2[3];
        color1[0] = sRGBtolinear((color/65536%256)/255.0);
        color1[1] = sRGBtolinear((color/256%256)/255.0);
        color1[2] = sRGBtolinear((color%256)/255.0);
        color2[0] = sRGBtolinear((palette[i]/65536%256)/255.0);
        color2[1] = sRGBtolinear((palette[i]/256%256)/255.0);
        color2[2] = sRGBtolinear((palette[i]%256)/255.0);
        double initdistance = sqrt((square(212671.0*(color1[0]-color2[0]))+square(715160.0*(color1[1]-color2[1]))+square(72169.0*(color1[2]-color2[2])))/561891144402.0);
        double brightness1 = ((212671.0*color1[0])+(715160.0*color1[1])+(72169.0*color1[2]))/1000000.0;
        double brightness2 = ((212671.0*color2[0])+(715160.0*color2[1])+(72169.0*color2[2]))/1000000.0;
        double sRGBbrightness1 = lineartosRGB(brightness1);
        double sRGBbrightness2 = lineartosRGB(brightness2);
        double brightnessdifference = brightness2 - brightness1;
        double sRGBbrightnessdifference = sRGBbrightness2 - sRGBbrightness1;
        if(brightness1 == brightness2){
            brightnessdifference = 1;
            sRGBbrightnessdifference = lineartosRGBderivative(brightness1);
        }
        double result = initdistance*(sRGBbrightnessdifference/brightnessdifference);
        if(result < maxerror){
            index = i;
            maxerror = result;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

int main(){
    const uint64_t amountofcolors = 216;
    uint32_t palette[amountofcolors];
    for(uint64_t i=0; i<216; i++){
        palette[i] = i%6*0x000033 + i/6%6*0x003300 + i/36%6*0x330000;
    } // sample palette
    volatile uint32_t color;
    for(uint64_t i=0; i<65536; i++){
        color = (rand()%4096)+(rand()%4096*4096);
        color = palette[selectnearest(palette, amountofcolors, color)];
    }
}
```

To a person who does not know any code, this does not appear inefficient until it is run. What happened here? The process returned zero, and the execution time is 31.141 seconds. Now, it might seem like this is quite fast for 65536 colors to quantize to the palette, however you could imagine how a dynamic script to play a 256×256 movie in a reduced palette will play in 0.03 fps. Could this be a processing error and I have to try again? No, because the next time it is not much better at 31.085 seconds, and again at 31.110 seconds. Now, you could argue that a different color picker algorithm would be faster, however that is not the point because they don't pick colors the same way, the point is to make this specific algorithm faster, but still pick the colors about the same way. What should be done in order to improve the efficiency of this method?

Comment: Does the time improve when you compile -O3 which is the maximum optimization the compiler can perform?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of performance aspects that can be improved in your code. I will cover general suggestions assuming that this code is for Win32 target. I will use minGw compiler with c11 standard.

**Compiler Optimizations:**
Without optimization code runs about 12.8 seconds on my PC. With -O3 optimization flag it takes about 10.6 seconds (about 17% faster).

**Data types and arithmetic operations:**
double type and constants with high precision are used in the code. Do you really need this precision? Moreover infinity is used in maxerror variable: `double maxerror = 1.0/0.0;` Consider to use `DBL_MAX` instead of inf. If performance is important then general algorythm of data types selection is following:

1. Can I use integer arithmetics? Prefereably int/uint types with logical/shift operations.
2. If not, then can I use float?
3. If not, then chose double or more precise types.
4. If floating point data types are used then consider NOT using floating point exceptions, NaN, Inf and denormal values. All these things can be very slow.

For example, you extract color components in the following way:

```
color1[0] = sRGBtolinear((color/65536%256)/255.0);
```

Here integer division can be replaced by bitwise/shift operations which is much faster. Assembly code will be almost 3 times shorter.

```
color1[0] = sRGBtolinear(((color >> 16) & 0xff)/255.0);
```

**Inlining:**
As it has been already mentioned `inline` keyword is confusing nowadays. Compilers have attributes or pragmas to always_inline/force_inline or noinline functions, because it is very important in some cases. E.g. if you want to insert assembly code with label in function wich compiler decided to inline. In this case compilation will fail. Only prohibiting inlining can help. In our case functions `lineartosRGBOrig` and `lineartosRGBderivativeOrig` can't be inlined because they are recursive. By the way, this recursion is not needed because input to these functions is always positive in current algorithm.

**Algorithm changes and code rearrangment:**

- It is better to move variables declarations from the loop.
- Values related to `color` in function `selectnearest` can be calculated only once istead of recalculation `palettelength` times.
- `RGBtolinear` data can be precalculated as a table with 255 elements to significantly improve performance.
- `initdistance` and brightness values are used only in comparison which allows us to remove `sqrt` operation and some divisions because we don't need exact values. Only relation is important.

**Some brief optimizations:**
I have made some optimizations that improved performance by 86% to original code compiled with -O3 flag and by 89% to code compiled without optimization. The code is not perfect but it is much faster.

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")

double gRgbToLinearTable[255];

void InitRgbToLinearTable(){
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < 255u; ++i)
    {
        double val = i / 255.0;
        gRgbToLinearTable[i] = (val > 0.0404482362771082 ? pow((val+0.055)/1.055, 2.4) : val/12.92);
    }
}

[[gnu::always_inline]] inline double square(double x) { return x*x; }

[[gnu::always_inline, gnu::flatten]] inline void sRGBtolinear(double* outComponents, uint32_t color){
    outComponents[0] = gRgbToLinearTable[(color >> 16) & 0xff];
    outComponents[1] = gRgbToLinearTable[(color >> 8) & 0xff];
    outComponents[2] = gRgbToLinearTable[color & 0xff];
}

[[gnu::always_inline, gnu::flatten]] inline double lineartosRGB(double input){
    if (input > 0.00313066844250063)
        return (pow(input, 0.4166666666666667)*1.055-0.055);
    else
        return input*12.92;
}

[[gnu::always_inline, gnu::flatten]] inline double lineartosRGBderivative(double input){
    if(std::abs(input) > 0.00313066844250063) return pow(input, -0.5833333333333334)*0.4166666666666667*1.055;
    else return 12.92;
}

size_t selectnearest(const uint32_t* palette, size_t palettelength, uint32_t color)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    double maxerror = DBL_MAX;
    double colors[2][3];
    double initdistance, brightness[2], rgbBrightness[2], brightnessdifference, sRGBbrightnessdifference;
    sRGBtolinear(colors[0], color);
    brightness[0] = (0.212671*colors[0][0])+(0.715160*colors[0][1])+(0.072169*colors[0][2]);
    rgbBrightness[0] = lineartosRGB(brightness[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < palettelength; i++)
    {
        if (palette[i] != color)
        {
            sRGBtolinear(colors[1], palette[i]);

            initdistance = (square(0.212671*(colors[0][0]-colors[1][0]))+square(0.212671*(colors[0][1]-colors[1][1]))+square(0.072169*(colors[0][2]-colors[1][2])));
            brightness[1] = (0.212671*colors[1][0])+(0.715160*colors[1][1])+(0.072169*colors[1][2]);
            rgbBrightness[1] = lineartosRGB(brightness[1]);

            if(brightness[0] != brightness[1])
            {
                brightnessdifference = brightness[1] - brightness[0];
                sRGBbrightnessdifference = rgbBrightness[1] - rgbBrightness[0];
            }
            else
            {
                brightnessdifference = 1.0 ;
                sRGBbrightnessdifference = lineartosRGBderivative(brightness[0]);
            }

            double result = initdistance*(sRGBbrightnessdifference/brightnessdifference);
            if(result < maxerror){
                index = i;
                maxerror = result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}

uint32_t* MakeSamplePalette(size_t amountOfColors)
{
    uint32_t* pResult = new uint32_t[amountOfColors];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < amountOfColors; i++)
    {
        pResult[i] = i%6*0x000033 + i/6%6*0x003300 + i/36%6*0x330000;
    }

    return pResult;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t amountofcolors = 216u;
    uint32_t* palette = MakeSamplePalette(amountofcolors);
    volatile uint32_t color;

    InitRgbToLinearTable();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 65536u; i++){
        color = (static_cast<unsigned int>(rand()) & 0xfff)+(static_cast<unsigned int>((rand()) & 0xfff) << 12);
        color = palette[selectnearest(palette, amountofcolors, color)];
    }

    delete[] palette;
    return color;
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with some suggestions to *improve your code performance*

- Extract from the loops any variable declaration.
- If a variable is called only to assign a value or execute an operation *only one* time, you should replace the value assigned to that variable in its place.
- Numeric values which are in the code should be either avoided or if they are needed, turned in constants.
- Repeated lines or code blocks are candidates to be written as functions.
- If you use compiler optimization it could make your code run faster (but be careful, some unexpected things may happen).

I made the following refactor to your code in order to optimize it:

```
double compute_brightness(double *color) //pointer = avoids array copy
{
    return ((212671.0*color[0])+(715160.0*color[1])+(72169.0*color[2]))/1000000.0;
}

//this value is constant but it gets created each time the function is called
//(consider to use INFINITY from <cmath>)
const double maxerror = 1.0/0.0;

uint64_t selectnearest(uint32_t* palette, uint64_t palettelength, uint32_t color)
{
    uint64_t index = 0;
    double color1[3];
    double color2[3];
    double brightness1;
    double brightness2;
    double brightnessdifference;
    double sRGBbrightnessdifference;
    double result;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < palettelength; i++)
    {
        //...
        brightness1 = compute_brightness(color1);//the same operation is applied
        brightness2 = compute_brightness(color2);//to these arrays
        //the value of `brightnessdifference` and `sRGBbrightnessdifference`
        //depends on this if, the else avoids to compute unused values
        if (brightness1 == brightness2)
        {
            brightnessdifference = 1;
            sRGBbrightnessdifference = lineartosRGBderivative(brightness1);
        }
        else
        {
            brightnessdifference = brightness2 - brightness1;
            sRGBbrightnessdifference = lineartosRGB(brightness2) - lineartosRGB(brightness1);
        }
        result = sqrt((square(212671.0*(color1[0]-color2[0])) + 
            square(715160.0*(color1[1]-color2[1]))+square(72169.0*(color1[2]-color2[2])))/561891144402.0) *
                (sRGBbrightnessdifference/brightnessdifference);
        if (result < maxerror)
        {
            index = i;
            maxerror = result;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

int main()
{
    //...
    volatile uint32_t color;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
        color = palette[selectnearest(palette, amountofcolors, (rand()%4096)+(rand()%4096*4096))];
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Any code that includes division by zero should be looked at hard.

Answer (score 2):

**Obsolete Keywords**
The C++ keyword inline is a [recommendation to the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796264/is-there-still-a-use-for-inline) and it won't necessarily do anything. It has been basically obsolete since C++03. When the optimization flags are used during compilation, the compiler will decide what can be inlined and take care of it.

**Division by Zero**
This program should either throw a `division by zero` exception or the compiler should complain on the following line (my compiler complained and wouldn't build the code).

```
double maxerror = 1.0/0.0;
```

**Inconsistent Usage of Symbolic Constants**
This code in main is inconsistent:

```
int main(){
    const uint64_t amountofcolors = 216;
    uint32_t palette[amountofcolors];
    for(uint64_t i=0; i<216; i++){
        palette[i] = i%6*0x000033 + i/6%6*0x003300 + i/36%6*0x330000;
    } // sample palette
```

The use of the numeric constant 216 in the for loop should be changed to use `amountofcolors`. That way if the value of `amountofcolors` changes the for loop will use the correct value.

**The use of uint64_t**
Rather than specify uint32_t or uint64_t just use `unsigned`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `size_t`. This will automatically choose the size of the value based on the word size of the computer and that will provide the fastest code.

**More Symbolic Constants Are Better**
The numeric constants `0x000033`, `0x003300` and `0x330000` are apparently some versions of RED, GREEN and BLUE. It might help others that need to modify the code if they had a better idea of what the values were so use symbolic constants, it won't hurt the performance.

The numeric constant `12.92` is used in 3 inline functions, if it has the same meaning for all 3 functions then a symbolic constant is called for so that all 3 functions can be changed at the same time

**Use of the `rand()` Function Without Seeding**
There is nothing random about this code since rand was never seeded.

```
        color = (rand()%4096)+(rand()%4096*4096);
```

**Using C Include Headers in C++**
In C++ standard C include headers can be included by adding a `c` to the front of the name and removing the `.h`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
```

I'm going to stop here because there is enough to fix without addressing any more, post a follow up question when you've taken care of this.

Comment: No, a compiler should not throw an exception or refuse to compile the code. 1.0/0.0 is defined as postiive infinity according to IEEE754 and any compiler not doing so will violate the C specification (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Computer_arithmetic)